# File name changed while uploading with NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, nsurlconnection

I am trying to upload some image file from the iPhone to my web server where I am using NSURLConnection for posting the data with sendSynchronousRequest.

I am making my body ready through appending couple of string which are given below.

```
NSString *check = @"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=";
check = [check stringByAppendingString:@"\""];
check = [check stringByAppendingString:randomNumber];
check = [check stringByAppendingString:@".jpg"];
check = [check stringByAppendingString:@"\""];
check = [check stringByAppendingString:@"'\r\n'"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:check] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:app.imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];

// now lets make the connection to the web
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

However when I try to get the image file in the server it shows right name with a " and a ' after the file name.

Answer (score 0):

You add this signs in your code:

```
check = [check stringByAppendingString:@"\""];
check = [check stringByAppendingString:@"'\r\n'"];
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are actually adding the " and the ' on line 5 and 6 of your code. Replace those lines with a single line that only adds the line feed:

```
check = [check stringByAppendingString:@"\r\n"];
```

An even better approach would be to use an asynchronous call that will not stop your main UI thread from responding. Use a framework like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) to get a nicer abstraction level. In AFNetworking, use can do multipart posts much easier.